# Paypal support not answering to my message

Tags: paypal

I really need to refund, but paypal support does not answer me, the pay is already completed and the one who got the money declined the refund I need help, because the email was mistaken and the money was sent to a wrong person

Comment: Personal issue with Pay pal management

Comment: 1. it's the weekend 2. call them, because they suck at email

Answer (score 0):

from my understanding if you refund to the wrong person via email it is the sender's responsibility to follow up with the receiver and ask for it back. But if the email does not belong to a paypal account it will automatically be cancelled and returned back to you around 30 days; [per user agreement.](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full)

3.7 Refused and Refunded Transactions. When you send money, the recipient is not required to accept it. You agree that you will not hold PayPal liable for any damages resulting from a recipient's decision not to accept a payment made through the PayPal Services. Any unclaimed, refunded or denied payment will be returned to your Balance or to the original Payment Method. We will return any unclaimed payment to you within 30 Days of the date you initiated payment.